# How do I automatically create checkboxes in Google Sheets if checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript

I want to automatically create checkboxes if a checkbox is checked

I have checkboxes in column 1(A)

and I want checkboxes to be made from B1 to E1 if A1 is checked

B2 to E2 if A2 is checked and so on

I also tried adding sheet.getLastRow in the script so it adds new checkboxes until the last row

but I don't know where I got it wrong. (It's the first time I tried using any kind of script)

Can you help me? Thanks in advance

[Google Spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UU4Y.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.